# MVC and View in Model

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm creating application with Codeigniter and MVC pattern. 
I'm at the point where I want to create a reusable administration tools for diffrent object like entry, user, category. I will need specific sets of tools across diffrent controllers and views and multiple time.

I want to be able to call something like `$this->load_admin_tools($name,$data)` where `$name` will be the name of tool sets (which will be just a html forms) and `$data` necessary variables to process those forms (most likely `$id` of an object).

I want to do that so I could in one place add or remove some tools.

I was thinking to create a model_admin_tools where I will check for permission if the tools should be displayed and then load proper view (with forms to delete/edit/etc). I know that those should be a Controller (to check permissions and then decide if show something or not) but repeating same code over and over again it's worst for me than putting those in to model. I could create private function in controller but then I would have to that function put in all my controllers.

Is there a better way to achieve this? I was thinking helpers, but again, helpers are not for "view". Or maybe I'm just too officious?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not bad practice to use a helpers in a view. One helper that I use all the time in my views are the url helper.

If you want a set of tools that can be used across many controllers, just create a model that does whatever, and then in each of your controllers you can just load that model and then call the function. That's the purpose of models is to be reused.

Also - you can return a view as a variable by setting a third parameter to true. See the very bottom of this page: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Example Controller method:

```
public function method()
{
    $this->load->model('myModel');
    $var = $this->myModel->modelMethod();

    if($var == true) {
        $data['sectionOne'] = $this->load->view('myView', '', true);
    }

    $this->load->view('layout', $data);

}
```

Comment: yes, I use helpers all the time, but I'm not loading a view in them. To clarify. I want to load let say 5 diffrent html forms (like edit/delete/ban etc) for user actions. So I need to check if it should be loaded and what kind of forms. Then I need to load proper html forms (views). So at the end, it would be `$this->load->view('user_delete_form')` in the model. And as I know this should be done in Controller. Thats why I'm a little bit confused and I wonder if there is better way to do it.

Comment: See my edited answer to see if that helps answer your question.

Comment: it's not exactly what I want to achieve, because that way I would have to call model, check result and then load view. That block of code will be many many times across controllers ;) Ideally would be to put that code to one function (like in model) and just call it. But that way I will have `load->view()` in model. I don't know if it's possible I need to check. I mean, I could create switch in view and based on second parameter for loading view showing the one I need. Even if I can't do it with one line of code (check, load needed view) 3 line is much better than 20

Comment: Do it how you wish, but if you load a view from a model, that model function is not necessarily reusable. It may be more applicable in your case to load the view in the model, although i'm all for model reuse (even if it is 3 lines of code to get the result in a view) rather than loading views from a model.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. That's why I asked. For future, do you think that HMVC would solved that kind of problem? I'm too advance in this project to even consider to jump into it, but I was reading about it some time ago and just out of curiosity i'm asking, maybe you will know.